# Google analytics language stats seems contradictory

Tags: seo, google-analytics, local-seo, internationalization, localization

On the 15th of February I decided to translate two pages of one site to 5 languages:
 - Russian
 - Korean
 - Chinese Simplified
 - Spanish

Now I get what appears to me to be contradictory results.

`es` language suddenly went down to nearly null, but `es-es` went up quite a lot. (And the rest of spanish speaking countries kept almost he same or went up, such as `es-mx`, `es-ar`, `es-us`, `es-419`, `es-cl` etc)

How can we explain this? Isn't `es` the total combination of all spanish languages from different countries?

Big drown down on `es`:

[image]

Big raise on `es-es`:

[image]

I'm experimenting exactly the same with Russian `ru` which went down quite a lot while `ru-ru` went up like crazy.

The site uses `es`, `ru`, `ko`, `en`, `zh-Hans` in the following `lang` tag depending on which language version of the site is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
```

I'm also using 5 `rel="alternate"` in all 5 versions of the site. Each pointing to the alternate language.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/page/" hreflang="en">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/page/zh/" hreflang="zh">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/page/ko/" hreflang="ko">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/page/es/" hreflang="es">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/page/ru/" hreflang="ru">
```

Interesting also that I saw the same exact decrement in visits in some other languages for which I have no translation, such as `de` or `fr`, while I saw the same increase in `de-de` and `fr-fr`.

**But** it is not something happening in all other languages, for example, `ja` (japanese) stays the same, even tho I have no translation for it either.

## Update:

Here's the graphic for the `de` and `de-de` languages.
Remember, my site is NOT translated to german, and Germany is practically only spoken in Germany:

`de`
[image]

`de-de`

[image]

And here are the ones for Italian, also not very spoken outside Italy:

`it` goes down almost disappearing:
[image]

`it-it` goes up quite a lot:
[image]

And here's the plot of both rows at the same time for `de` and `de-de`:
[image]

Here's another interesting graph regarding korean (only spoken in North and South Korea), where suddenly, all Korean browsers start reporting the country bit? Makes me wonder... could all this be due to a new versions of lets say, Chrome browser? That starts reporting things that didn't before?

Anyone with any Google Analytics account can verify they are having the same results as me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't `es` the total combination of all spanish languages from different countries?

No. Google Analytics is reporting the exact browser language settings of each visitor. So for any given Spanish-language page, you will most likely see a mix of reported browser languages, e.g. `es`, `es-ES`, `es-US`.

Because there's no y-axis visible on your screenshots, it's hard to say exactly what's happening. But based on my experience, it's this:

- When you had no translated pages, your site got a mix of browser languages - mostly variants of `en`. But some `es`, `ru`, etc.
- Once you created the Spanish version with the correct `hreflang` tags, Google gave a big boost to that page for searchers using Google.es.
- Your Spanish page has no region targetting -- you're using the generic catchall `hreflang="es"`. However your *visitors* do have the regional information set in their browser, so you see the big increase in `es-ES`.
- Hopefully, the increase in `es-*` traffic is greater than the decline in `es` generic traffic. But this can't be determined from your screenshots. Everything looks to be working as designed though.

Comment: I've updated my question with new charts with Y axes and German language, one for which I have not added translation in my site and which is practically only spoken in Germany. As I said, the same happens with other languages like French and Italian.

Comment: Interesting the Korean case...